# Загрузка файлов на drag-and-drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-n-drop

Кто может подсказать, как сделать чтобы:

1. Чтобы как в вк за пределами блока нельзя было перетаскивать файл (красным на скриншоте)
2. Как сделать чтобы при перетаскивании на окно появлялось (то что в зеленым на скриншоте)

У меня есть несколько путей решения 2, первое это например отдельно отслеживать перенос на окно:

```
  $(window).bind('dragenter dragover', function(event){ Тут появления блока в окне});
```

И второй путь решения, менее удачный, это полностью отслеживать `dragover` и `drop` и т.п только на окне, но с помощью `event.target` выделять определенные действия.

[image]

P.S: Больше интересует, как сделать первое, но если предложите лучшие пути решения второго, буду рад. Желательно код на Jquery, но JS тоже воспринимаю.

Comment: @zkolya Нужно, без библеотек

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Покопавшись в зарубежных источниках и переведя несколько статей о `drag-and-drop`, я все же сам решил вопрос.

Все было очень просто, нужно было в `dragover` после проверки на выход за границу элемента вписать: `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none";`

Пример:

```
$('#box_drop').bind('dragenter dragover', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if($(event.target).parents().filter('#drop_upload_cont').length >= 1) {
        $('#drop_upload').html('Отпустите мышку').show();
    }else{
        $('#drop_upload').html('Тащите файл в поле').show();
        event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо отслеживать события `dragover`, `dragleave`, `mouseleave` на `window` или `html` или `body` (как лучше сработает), добавить классы в `body` и в `css` изменять стили, как необходимо у курсора, блока для перетаскивания и тд.

Comment: У меня, сам блок с рабочей загрузкой drag-and-drop готов, вопрос был в том, что как сделать чтобы перенос в эту зону был вообще не возможен и покапавшись и переведя несколько статей о drag-and-drop я все же сам решил вопрос, все было очень просто `event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none";`